# Node.js Query Parameters for Smartsheet API

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am trying to send `include` parameters with a get-sheet request [smartsheet.sheets.getSheet(options)](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet) using the Node.js sdk. The API documentation is vague on how to add the `include` parameters in the API call.

I found a Smartsheet Developers Blog post [Demystifying Query Parameters in the Smartsheet API](https://developers.smartsheet.com/blog/demystifying-query-parameters-in-the-smartsheet-api) that provides more guidance, but the Node.js example code they provide is invalid javascript:

```
// Set options
var options = {
    queryParameters: {
    include: "attachments",
    include: "source",
    includeAll: true
    }
};

// List sheets
smartsheet.sheets.listSheets(options)
    .then(function(response) {

    ...
```

In the above code the last `include` query parameter will override all of the prior values and you will be left with a `options` variable that looses the "attachements" parameter:

```
  queryParameters: {
    include: "source",
    includeAll: true
  }
```

To me the obvious solutions would be for `include` to take an array like:

```
    include: ["attachments", "source"],
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try a comma separated list? `include: "attachments,source"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of using the SDK whatever values needed for the `include` query string are added to the URL as a comma separated list. The SDK will take the value you provide for the `include` parameter of the `queryParameters` object and add that as the value for the `include` query string and append it to the URL.
Instead of providing the `include` parameter multiple times in the `queryParameters` object or providing an array you would give a single `string` value for `include` with all of the options you wish to use comma separated.
For example, a `GET Sheet` request that asks for the `source` info and `attachments` to be included would look like this:

```
const options = {
    id:<SHEET_ID>,
    queryParameters : {
        include: 'source,attachments',
        includeAll: true
    }
}

smartsheet.sheets.getSheet(options)
.then(sheet => {
    console.log(sheet);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Note, the `includeAll` query string is for `pagination` and can be used separately to have all rows of the sheet included in the response.
Also, if you are running test requests in your console and set `logLevel: 'info'` when creating your Smartsheet client with the access token you can see the URL being used for the request get printed out above the sheet data response and it will show you how the URL is being structured.